# How do I return a value from a javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, return-type

Say I have a function

```
function myFunction(myValue) {

    // do something

}
```

How would I return a value from this, say a string type after the method is executed?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

Comment: That isn't a jQuery function.

Comment: Since Javascript isn't strictly typed, while you can easily return a string as shown below, you aren't going to have a strict return type from your method, etc.

Answer (score 12):

Use the `return` statement:

```
return "Hello";
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Statements/return

---

Also, JavaScript is dynamically typed so you don't have to specify a type for the function, just return the variable.

Comment: jQuery equivalent: `return $("Hello".split("")).map(function(){ return this }).get().join("");`

Answer (score 8):

```
function myFunction(myValue) {
  // do something

  // return to caller of function:
  return myValue;
}

var result = myFunction(myValue);
```